# Optimum Unity Android splash image resolution

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, splash-screen

I've Unity Plus and I'm trying to find out the optimum android splash screen size that fits all android devices as there's no option to specify multiple images with different resolutions for android.

So far I've tried 768x1024, 1536x2048 on every option(center, fill, fit), however some nexus tablets/phones won't display the splash image full screen correctly.

Is there an optimum/suggested image resolution/configuration for android devices that most likely fit all?

Comment: nowadays android notch results in quit random screen size unity getting, this is more difficult. did you find the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `Splash Scaling` property in Player Settings for Android builds. Try setting it to `Scale to fill (cropped)`. Your splash image will be scaled without changing the aspect ratio.

We are using 1280x720 image in Unity 5.3.4 for android builds without any problem.

The image will be cropped but if there is not any sensitive text or symbol on the edges that will not be a problem.

Hope this helps.

[image: Unity Editor Android Settings Screenshot]

Comment: It's odd that providing a landscape aspect ratio for a portrait splash screen resolves the problem. I guess the documentation wasn't very clear to me.. thanks a lot @ilkinulas

Comment: @gencay are meaning providing a landscape image for portrait app?what's your app orientation setting? not working. I found that my splash scalling setting never ends up anything difference in real apps. Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you'll want to include multiple copies of the image at different resolutions and aspect ratios in your deployment. For example, small and large, both with different ARs. You would read the screensize of the device and select the appropriate size image for the device.

To give more detail here, I worked on a game that targeted devices from small screen sizes (Galaxy Ace), to large tablets (Galaxy Note 10.1). We used our own splash screen implementation rather than unity's, and we calculated the aspect ratio of the device. We then checked the screen resolution. After that, we had enough info to select the appropriate resolution image for the screen. It costs a bit more space, but it looks nice and crisp on almost every device.

Comment: Thanks @forsamori.. Though that sounds like a very crude way to achieve this. I'm surprised that unity doesn't offer an option to provide multiple images for different densities specified here: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I think when we implemented this Unity had very rudimentary splashscreen functionality. Something tells me that it does what I've specified above natively now, though I'm not too sure where you'd find it.